# Sin function not giving correct answer

Tags: php, trigonometry

can someone explain to me why my sin function is not returning the correct value when i try to calculate some sin values...

```
echo sin(2 * pi()); //returns -2.44929359829E-16 (should be 1)
echo sin(1.9 * pi()); //returns -0.309016994375 (correct)
echo sin(1 * pi()); //returns 1.22464679915E-16 (should be 0)
echo sin(1.00001 * pi()); //returns -3.14159265309E-5 (correct)
echo sin(1.2 * pi()); //returns -0.587785252292 (correct)
echo sin(0.1 * pi()); //returns 0.309016994375 (correct)
echo sin(0 * pi()); //returns 0 (correct)
echo sin(1.5 * pi()); //returns -1 (correct)
```

all cosine values are working correctly

Comment: Just checking... are you expecting degrees or radians?

Comment: The values close to 0 and 1 are reasonably close. You might be encountering floating point errors.

Comment: Sin(Pi) == 0 as well as Sin(2*Pi) == 0. What you see is just a rounding errors

Comment: expecting radians. as mentioned below with floating point double precision it's fine but i'm not sure how exact i have to be with these values down the track.

Answer (score 5):

> echo sin(2 * pi()); //returns -2.44929359829E-16 (should be 1)

Should be 0. It's close enough for floating point at double precision.

> echo sin(1 * pi()); //returns 1.22464679915E-16 (should be 0)

Close enough for floating point at double precision.

Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

It's because pi() Return the value 3.1415926535898, which is an estimated value.

For a more accurate pi value, try to use M_PI, which has the value 3.14159265358979323846

For more information on pi in php read this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pi.php